# how to handle special characters in input field in my angular app

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

when I try to edit  `16" Super` in input field it becomes `<p> 16&quot; Super` i were tried [innerHTML] but for submitting I need to bind the data using [(ngModel)]. using both [(ngModel)]="" and [innerHTML]="" is not displayiong any data.
input field is
 `<input type="text" class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Product Name"  [(ngModel)]="products['product_description'][1]['name'] "required  name="product_description[1][name]">`

I want to use to way binding.

and it displays the `<p>` tag also how to eliminate this.

Comment: can you add more code to explain your problem

Comment: I have created a form in angular. I bind data using [(ngModel)]  in my input field the data-bind  shows  `16&quot; Super` like this, but actually I need like this `16" Super` in input field

Comment: by `form` what you are meaning. do you have `text field` or a plain `div` tag?

Comment: sorry, Arvind. i just updated my code

Comment: any other details??

Answer (score 0):

Check input field type. It should be text.